# User Permissions SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, permissions, custom, user

I am working with SharePoint 2010. My requirement is to have some user groups blocked for some of my custom pages those reside in "Site Pages" library.So that users in those groups can not access the specified pages.
I am not sure how to achieve this.Could you please provide some links to documentation on permissions management in SharePoint 2010.

Thanks
Vivek

Comment: Is there anyway we can stop authenticated users from view Site Pages library. The users should still have access to the pages in Site Pages library Thanks in adavance

Comment: It depends on the role assigned to authenticated users. Like a guest can still access the pages but not the library.Try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your pages reside in a document library typically named as 'Pages' or 'Site Pages' what you need to do is go to manage permissions for the custom page and stop inheriting permissions.

You need to give unique permissions to those pages and just grant users/groups whom you wish to make these pages accessible. That ways you can exclude group or a user to whom you do not wish to give access to those particular pages. Its like giving exclusive permissions to only a few and restricting everyone else.

You can find a lot of good articles if you just google it with "sharepoint unique permissions" or "stop inheriting permissions sharepoint" ,etc.